# Error when deleting a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

I'm beginning and there is something that I don't understand with pointers.
I have the following code returning an error I don't know why:

```
std::string key = "myKey";    
const unsigned char* aesKey = reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char *> (key.c_str());

// Executing some stuffs

delete aesKey;
```

the first time the code executes everything works fine, but the second time i get an error which I don't get if I don't have the `delete` line (Instead I have a memory leak, quite worst).

Someone could explain me why this is not working?

The sample below is working fine in the same context (same method, ...)

```
unsigned char* test = new char;
//doing some stuff
delete test;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**First:** you don't own that C string, so it's not yours to `delete[]`. The `std::string` still owns it and will `delete[]` it later.

**Second:** arrays are deleted with `delete[]`, not `delete`. So you're using the wrong operator anyway.

Comment: Yes. To clarify, the OP's second example 1) uses `new`, so it should use `delete`, and 2) only allocates one char, not an array.

Comment: Thank you, as you can see i'm a real beginner and still having difficulties with pointers!
Will mark this answer as accepted asap!

Answer (score 2):

The memory returned by `std::string::c_str` continues to be owned by the string, so it shouldn't be `delete`d.

You should only call `delete` on memory that you have `new`ed, and you shouldn't use `new`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not delete the data receieved from `c_str()`. It points to internal location of the string and it's up to string to delete it

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to delete the pointer returned via `std::string::c_str()`. A good rule of thumb to remember is this: If you did not allocate memory for a pointer, you shouldn't be deallocating it. See the standard:

> **21.4.7.1 basic_string accessors**

```
 const charT* c_str() const noexcept;
 const charT* data() const noexcept;
```

> 1 *Returns*: A pointer p such that p + i == &operator for each i in [0,size()].
>
> 2 *Complexity*: constant time.
>
> 3 *Requires*: The program shall not alter any of the values stored in the character array.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of quick notes:

In your first example, you are deleting memory that you have not allocated. The contents of `aesKey` belong to the string `key` and you shoudl not delete them... if nothing else, when `key` is destroyed when it goes out of scope, it will attempt to delete the same block of memory and you'll get a nasty double delete bug.

In your second example, you are creating a `char` but assigning to an `unsigned char`. This is not a good idea, especially when you come to manipulating more complex datatypes.